# iOS shared cookie storage not synced with Ktor Client

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I'm running a shared KMM module with Ktor http client. I'm noticing that when I set a cookie on the iOS native side via [NSHttpCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage) that my Ktor HttpClient doesn't pick up the new cookie. If the server responds with a SetCookie header, that works fine. The problem is when I set the cookie manually on the iOS side. I have my client setup with this:

```
install(HttpCookies) {
  storage = AcceptAllCookiesStorage()
}
```

How does Ktor sync with the iOS NSHttpCookieStorage and is there a way to force it to sync? Hopefully I don't need to create an entirely new HttpClient anytime I want the cookies to sync.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ktor doesn't have syncing mechanism between `HttpCookies` plugin's storage and `NSHTTPCookieStorage`.

Comment: Seems like there is currently a bug that allows NSHttpCookieStorage to manage cookies simultaneously along with the AcceptAllCookiesStorage, causing some unintended behavior. Even when no cookie plugin is installed, NSHttpCookieStorage is still being used behind the scenes in my tests.